# How can I avoid getting "Your Dropbox is full" notification from Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

How can I configure Dropbox so that I don't get "Your Dropbox is full" notifications? It keeps appearing throughout the day:

[image]

I use dropbox on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comment, you can disable notifications from Dropbox entirely in Windows 7 by accessing the "Notification Area Icons" Control Panel Menu. Two ways to access this control panel:

1. Right-clicking the taskbar, clicking Properties, and "Customize..."
2. Entering the following into Windows Explorer: "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Notification Area Icons" and hitting Enter.

Then choose "Hide icon and notifications" for Dropbox.